# Changing Home directory of a NIS user

Tags: linux, unix, nfs

I have a networked setup of 20 odd systems running ubuntu Linux where users are allowed to login using NIS+NFS. 
I want to change a particular user's home directory. How can I do it (from any of the connected systems)

Answer (score 1):

NIS client will check against its own `/etc/passwd` file if an user exists in order to modify it. As it does not, the client `usermod` operation will fail.

To modify a NIS user home directory, login as root in the NIS server and run `usermod -d new_home -m username` and then `make -C /var/yp`, where /var/yp in the NIS server configuration directory. The last command will propagate the changes to the clients. If the `new_home` is not accessible from the server `usermod -m` will fail. It is good practice to export users home dirs on NFS and I assume this is your case.

Comment: Can I do this from a machine that holds the user's home but not the NIS server? I can simply use `yppasswd` from the client to modify the user's password, is there some solution like this?

Comment: No, because the user is NIS user and not present in client's /etc/passwd. Also, the other clients won't know about the change. You can change the user's home from the NIS server without moving it (skip the `-m` option in `usermod`). Then the clients will see the change and this specific machine will be able to access the new home, if it is local to it or exported via NFS.